# Using getElementById and getElementsByTagName together

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I have code that looks like so:

```
<ul id="effects-list" class="effects-list">
    <li data-creative="5">Creative</li>
</ul>
```

I am attempting to read the data attribute of that above HTML using the following code:

```
var effectData = document.getElementById("effects-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var creative = effectData.getAttribute('data-creative');
alert(creative)
```

The above code doesn't work. It throws the following error:

```
effectData.getAttribute is not a function
```

I am using jQuery on the page and originally tried this:

```
var effectData = $('.effects-list li');
```

Again, same error.

What do I have wrong and how do I fix this?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DQ47/1/) of the code.

Note: There are more `li` elements on the page and I am reading more data than just one `li` element. I am trying to avoid having to ad a separate id to each `li` element if I can help it.

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a collection, not a single `Element`. Note the plural `getElements...` vs. the singular `getElementById()`. You'll need to access an index: `...ByTagName("li")[0];`

Comment: Have you tried $("#effects-list").find("li").attr("data-creative") ?

Comment: use `var creative = effectData[0].getAttribute('data-creative');` as `effectData` is an array

Comment: @ArunPJohny - If I have more than one `li` element that method returns `null` for the second element.

Comment: using jQuery `var effectData = $('.effects-list li'); creative = effectData.data('creative')`

Comment: If you do have a reason to use plain JS instead of jQuery, why tag the question with jquery?

Comment: @Lynda sorry, not clear what you mean by null for second element

Comment: @Lynda see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PH7L7/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Apologies I wrote my code wrong. Your fiddle showed me where I was wrong. Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)** returns a list of elements with the given tag name, so you need to access the element inside this list using `[]`:

```
var effectData = document.getElementById("effects-list").getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DQ47/3/)**

If you're looking for jQuery solution, you can use **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**:

```
var creative = $('#effects-list').find('li').data('creative');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DQ47/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
var dataCreative = $("#effects-list li").attr('data-creative');
alert(dataCreative);
```

This is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DQ47/2/).

And if there are multiple `li` inside `ul` then you can use `.each`, see below code

```
$("#effects-list li").each(function(){
    var dataCreative = $(this).attr('data-creative');
    alert(dataCreative);
});
```